# How can a human get a tail?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, human

I would like to make a human who is able to use kobold tail attachments.

Because kobolds are humanoid, I could begin with the feat Racial Heritage choosing kobold, which qualifies me to use their race-specific items and feats, and then the kobold feat Tail terror, which allows me to use a tail for attacking and allows me to equip tail attachments.
However, I still wouldn't have a tail.

That's why I am curious - what options exist that could allow me to gain a tail as a human?

Comment: It has been ruled for your purposes that, while it grants you a tail-based natural attack, Tail Terror doesn't give you a tail?  Does that apply to other things that give you a tail or just Tail Terror?

Answer (score 6):

## There are at least a few

- the 2nd level witch spell [*Fair is Foul*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/f/fair-is-foul/) grants any character access to any number of permanent mutations from the changeling's arcane malignancy table.  One of the options is a tail. This is the best and cheapest option if you can get a minus 2 on the d100 roll somehow (then you could just cast a single maximized *Fair is Foul*).  Otherwise it's still pretty great but you will need 50 castings on average to get the result you want (which runs 3000 gp and will mean you probably want an average of 49 castings of *Remove Curse* or similar).
- the [*Phantom Limb*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/phantom-limb/) spell can be used to gain a tail and a swim speed for a short time, or to replace a 'missing' tail needed for other purposes for 24 hours.  It is, however, a 5th level spiritualist or 6th level psychic spell.
- the 3rd level spell [*Tail Strike*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/tail-strike/) gives you a tail for 1 minute/level.
- the 5th level spell [*Vengeful Stinger*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/v/vengeful-stinger/) gives you a tail for 1 round/level
- The 1st level spell [*Batrachian Surge*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/batrachian-surge/) gives you a tail for 1 round + 1 round/3 levels
- The 4th level spell [*Reincarnate*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/) can make you stop being human and instead be a race with a tail, but then you aren't human anymore, obviously.
- Polymorph subschool spells can often give you a tail, but they take your polymorph subschool spell slot and often have short durations. Wild Shape is somewhat better.
- A [*Monkey Belt*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/belt-monkey/) gives you a tail for 5 minutes per day, but limits what you can do with it.
- An [*Elixir of Two Worlds*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/e-g/elixir-of-two-worlds/) can give you a permanent (even more permanent that *Fair is Foul*) tail, but it comes at the cost of your legs, lowering your land speed to 5 ft.
- The [*Cloak of the Manta Ray*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/c-d/cloak-of-the-manta-ray/) lets you attack with a manta ray's tail spine.  That may or may not be close enough for you.
- [*Gelugon Armor*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-armor/specific-magic-armor/gelugon-armor/) has a tail, and a very nice one, but it's heavy armor and 117,650 gp.

Answer (score 6):

### The [Wilding](https://aonprd.com/FeatDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Wilding) feat:

> You were touched by nature at an early age and share a kinship with wild creatures. *Your body might bear animalistic features, such as bestial ears or a **tail***, or your presence may be subtly unlike that of others.
>
> Prerequisites: Any neutral alignment, must be taken at 1st level.
>
> Benefit: You gain the druid’s wild empathy ability, using your character level as your druid level. If you have one or more levels in a class that grants wild empathy, you gain an additional +3 bonus on wild empathy checks. You are treated as an animal for the purpose of harmful mind-affecting effects that target animals (such as charm animal).
>
> Special: A character who has this feat can select the Animal Soul or Aspect of the Beast feats without meeting the prerequisites.

This would allow you to have a tail.

From [this post](https://paizo.com/threads/rzs42krp?PFSLegal-HalfElf-Kitsune#5), designer was inspired to create the feat for stuff like this.

Comment: Perfect, this is excellent! Thanks!